# Date Validation --> end date must be greater than start date

Tags: django, datetime

I need to write a script where it validates the end date is greater than the start date.

Also the start date/end date can not be before the current date. This needs to be written in Django 1.8.

Comment: What did you try? What is not working with that?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow isn't a place to get others to write code for you.

Answer (score 10):

You can override the [**`Model.clean(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) for this. If you use a [**`ModelForm`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform), then it will automatically call `.clean()` on the model instance to check if the constraint is satisfied.

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class MyModel(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        if not (timezone.now() <= self.start <= self.end):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid start and end datetime')
```

As of [django-2.2](/questions/tagged/django-2.2), you can use [**`constraints`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.constraints) in the `Meta`:

```
# since Django-2.2

from django.db import models
from django.db.models import F, Q
from django.db.models.functions import Now

class MyModel(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        # ...
        pass

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(start__lte=F('end'), start__gte=Now()),
                name='correct_datetime'
            ),
        ]
```

Given the database system supports this, the constraints will be enforced at the database level as well.

Comment: Thanx for this detailed answer. I'd like to add that if dealing with date fields (no timestamp) then simply you can add the constrain as follows: 
`CheckConstraint(check=Q(date_test__gte=TruncDate(Now())), name="date_is_today",)` the `TrancDate` can be imported from: `from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate
`