# How do I check if the end date is not before the start date django

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I need to check that the end date of the event is not before the start date

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)
```

Comment: @BradSolomon That's not really helpful - the user doesn't know how to do those things. That's why they're asking.

Comment: yeah,that's my first question, What's missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Validation --> end date must be greater than start date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860065/date-validation-end-date-must-be-greater-than-start-date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise to look into signals in Django.
See URL: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/#pre-save

Here is a draft (untested) example you can try:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, editable=False, max_length=100)


def check_date(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.start_date > instance.end_date:
        raise ValueError('Start date must be less than end date')

pre_save.connect(check_date, sender=Event)
```

When saving with incorrect dates an error should be raised.