# Django CheckConstraints to check start_date greater than or equal today

Tags: django, django-models, django-constraints

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.db.models.functions import Now, TruncDay
    
    class Foo(models.Model):
      start_date = models.DateTimeField()
      end_date = models.DateTimeField()
    
      class Meta:
        constraints = [
          name="start_date must be greater than or equal today",
          check=CheckConstraints(start_date__gte=TruncDay(Now()))
        ]
```

like above code, I want to add CheckConstraint to check whether start_date is greater than or equal with today.
but, after makemigration and migrate, error happened.

`functions or expression 'CURRENT_TIME' cannot be userd in check clause`

I tried two ways.

#### first.

```
check = CheckConstraints(start_date__gte=timezone.now())
```

but, Migration File has result of timezone.now() method, like datetime(2022, 01, 06, tzinfo=<UTC>)

#### second.

```
check = CheckConstraints(start_date__gte=timezone.now)
```

and

```
check = CheckConstraints(start_date__gte=TruncDay(Now))
```

this trial make error `function cannot be resolved` when I tried to migrate.

How can I check start_date and today?



thanks and apologize for my English skills in advance.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56860179/11993840

Comment: that answer is using Now(). But when I tried that way and migrate, the error returned , "functions or expressions cannot be used in check clause."

Answer (score 2):

I think that error returned because of `CheckConstraint`. 
Your import: `from django.db import models` so you should use `models.CheckConstraint()`

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Now
from django.db.models import Q    

class Foo(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.CheckConstraint(
                check=Q(start_date__gte=Now()),
                name = "start_date must be greater than or equal today"
            )
    ]
```

It is explained in the docs, see [constraint reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints) for more info

Comment: CheckConstraint is not support in mariadb. "functions or expression 'CURRENT_TIME' cannot be userd in check clause" error occurs.